# How to limit an association collection in rails console with "as_json" Active Record methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, activerecord, rubygems

I'd like to display in rails console a limit collections (4 level) of the parent entity "Article", which would be a relationship between itself, and the example:

```
# article.rb

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Article', optional: true
 has_many :sub_articles, :class_name => 'Article', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end

def as_json(options={})
  super(methods: [:subarticles])
end
```

where the as_json (ActiveRecord) method is overwritten to show the recursion in the relation, for example:

```
 # rails console
 
  Article.first.as_json
  =>
  id: 1,
    name: "king article"
    created_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
    updated_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
    parent_id: nil
    sub_articles:
    [ Article:0x0000641428defb71
    id: 2,
      name: "pencils article"
      created_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
      updated_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
      parent_id: 1
      sub_articles:
        [ Article:0x0000621438defb71
        id: 3,
        name: "pencil child 1"
        created_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
        updated_at: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:14:26.463429000 UTC +00:00,
        parent_id: 2
        sub_articles: [],
```

And that can be extended even further, but I would like to extend the sub-article up to 4 levels... to such an extent that if a father has a great-great-grandson (sub_articles) it cannot be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
# in article.rb

def as_json(options={})
  super(methods: [:limited_hierarchy])
end

def level_in_hierarchy
  return 0 if parent_id.nil?
  return 1 if parent.parent_id.nil?
  return 2 if parent.parent.parent_id.nil?
  return 3 if parent.parent.parent.parent_id.nil?
  # ... etc
end

def limited_hierarchy
  return sub_articles if level_in_hierarchy < 4
  []
end
```

should work, the `level_in_hierarchy` method can be refactored to make it more performant, but I've left it this way for readability. We are only interested in whether the level_in_hierarchy is < 4, so it's not necessary to calculate the value for all levels.

Depending on the number of articles in the application, it might be a better choice to set the value of level_in_hierarchy as an attribute in the Article model at the time that the model is created. This will improve performance.

Comment: Excellent, it was what I was looking for, through the parents I can know at what level the son is. Thank you very much for your time: D

Answer (score 1):

I think a little adjustion of Les Nightingill's answer can do what you want.
Adding `attr_accesstor :level_in_hierarchy`:

```rb
# in article.rb
attr_accesstor :level_in_hierarchy

def as_json(options={})
  super(methods: [:limited_hierarchy])
end

def limited_hierarchy
  level_in_hierarchy ||= 0
  if level_in_hierarchy < 4
    sub_articles.each { |sub_a| sub_a.level_in_hierarchy = level_in_hierarchy + 1 }
    sub_articles 
  else
    []
  end
end
```

Comment: In the end what I did was take Les Nightingill's answer and refactor it based on its code. If I could mark the two options as the most useful, I would do it with great pleasure, because it also served me in your own way, Thank you very much for your time and answer: D